# Apache installation configuration can't find PCRE? ( pcre-config for libpcre not found )

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, apache-httpd

These are the requirements and instructions on how to install Apache on Linux.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html

So I've installed everything (`c++ compiler`, `apr` and `apr-util`) to be able to install Apache correctly.

The only thing left is PCRE, I've installed it and it's located in my `/usr/local/src/pcre-8.32`

As I'm trying to `sudo ./configure --with-included-apr` I get this error:

```
checking for pcre-config... false
configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solved it.

First I installed pcre in `/usr/local/pcre`, using

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre
make
sudo make install
```

Then installed apache with

```
./configure --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 10):

PCRE devel package is not installed on your system.
First install pcre-devel

```
sudo yum install pcre-devel -y
```

and then run

```
sudo ./configure --with-included-apr
```

it will automatically take pcre by default.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by giving the path in the Apache configuration

```
./configure \
--with-included-apr \
--with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin/pcre-config
```

as the compiler looks for the configuration settings in the pre-config file, hence we have to give the exact location of the pre-config file.