# build apache on linux server

Tags: linux, rhel, apache-httpd, compiling, pcre

I have downloaded pcre from https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre2-10.34.tar.gz and extracted it to 
/usr/local/lib

when I run

```
./configure --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/usr/local/lib/pcre2-10.34
```

I am getting following error

> configure: error: Did not find pcre-config script at
>   /usr/local/lib/pcre2-10.34

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache installation configuration can't find PCRE? ( pcre-config for libpcre not found )](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66692/apache-installation-configuration-cant-find-pcre-pcre-config-for-libpcre-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum install pcre-devel -y
```

fixed the issue, the devel(development) package was missing.